# Watchdog CPU/Power usage

Tags: python, windows, watchdog

I'm trying to create a simple file renamer using watchdog in python, it is very simple, any created "xlsx" file will be rename to "Base.xslx"

I got it quickly by using the code below, but when running it uses a lot of CPU and power, is there anything wrong with the code itself or this is normal?

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import time
import os

fp = 'C:/yourpath/'

class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        time.sleep(1)
        for file_name in os.listdir(fp):
            if '.xlsx' in file_name:
                name=fp+file_name
                os.rename(name,"Base.xlsx")


observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() 
observer.schedule(event_handler, path=fp)
observer.start()


try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Comment: Also looking for answer! :)

Comment: Interested in this problem as well. How expansive is '/yourpath/'? If there's a huge number of existing files I'm guessing there's a necessary performance hit?

Comment: Hi Justin, my path is a box drive path, with multiple subfolders, files and big path name, but i don't think this is the cause, because i've tried with simple paths. like D:/foo and D:/bar and got huge amounts of usage to.

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that `time.sleep(0)` is one of the problems. Observer class is event based, so it isn't monitoring the folder according to the parameter of the sleep in the infinite cycle, but it's going to run the handler method as soon as the event is arrived from the OS.

This infinite cycle is using a whole CPU core (as empty infinite cycles usually do), so you should change the `time.sleep()` parameter to `1` (or anything else bigger than that, it won't matter as `KeyboardInterrupt`  will interrupt the sleep method regardless its 'length').

Also you should use `PatternMatchingEventHandler()`, it has almost the same functionality as yours but it only examine the newly created file (not every file, for each handler method call), and you don't even need to write any new class.